# Is there a way to convert a perl array to a hash using a the map {} operator because a simple assignment isn't enough

Tags: perl

I'm writing a better version of sed basically (I need it for some ETL work).

```
cat file.txt | transform [regex] [replaceor] [regex] [replaceor] [regex replaceor]... 

my %transforms = @ARGV; # convert array (regex,replace,regex,replace) pairs into hash
# want something like this:
# my %transforms = map { qr/$_/ => $_[++]} @ARGV; # grab TWO element of @ARGV at a time

while (my $content = <STDIN>) {
   while (my ($scan, $print) = each(%transforms)) {
   # $print could be code. Still deciding on that.
   my $scan = qr/$scan/;  # WANT TO AVOID re-compiling the regex every time
   my $transformed = $content =~ s/$scan/$print/re; #                                                          
   print $transformed;
  }
}
```

Yes, I could do this with brute force and many other ways but this grabbing multiple items from an array has come up for me several times and I wonder if there is a trick to it. Hmm. What about a double map?

Comment: So .. `my @ary = qw(a b c d); my %h = @ary;`  results in `%h` hash being `(a => b, c => d`)`.  What part of that is not working?  If it is indeed _always_ two-by-two then this is precisely what you want.  There are a number of other ways with Perl's flexibitly but what is broken that you need to fix?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but why do you think you need to have these values in a hash.....? That is literally quite unnecessary. Also, you declare `$scan` twice in the same scope. And that "regex optimization" is not going to improve your regex, since `$scan` goes out of scope each loop iteration.

Comment: *I'm writing a better version of sed* -- well, to be honest, it LOOKS like you are inventing a worse version of Perl.... This `while ... print` logic is `perl -p`. This regex/replaceor thing is literally the substitution operator, give or take a few characters. If you supply some samples of what you are trying to do, you'd get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

[pairmap](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#pairmap) grabs 2 items at a time from an array:

```
use List::Util qw(pairmap);
my %transforms = pairmap { qr/$a/, $b } @ARGV;
```

Comment: In the end I settled on using an array of arrays, no need for an array of hashes like someone stated above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```perl
use List::Util qw( pairmap );

my %transforms = pairmap { qr/$a/ => $b } @ARGV;
```

or

```perl
my %paired_args = @ARGV;

my %transforms = map { qr/$_/ => $paired_args{$_} } keys( %paired_args );
```

---

But hash keys are always strings. The above is equivalent to

```perl
use List::Util qw( pairmap );

my %transforms = pairmap { my $re = qr/$a/; "$re" => $b } @ARGV;
```

And that is effectively equivalent to the following (or something similar):

```perl
my %transforms = pairmap { "(?^u:$a)" => $b } @ARGV;
```

You're hoping to compile the patterns once each, but this doesn't achieve that. You're actually causing each pattern to be compiled one extra time!

You don't actually need to look up values by key, so an array of arrays would do the trick here.

```perl
use List::Util qw( pairmap );

my @transforms = pairmap { [ qr/$a/, $b ] } @ARGV;

while ( my $content = <STDIN> ) {
   for ( @transforms ) {
      my ( $scan, $print ) = @$_;
      $content =~ s/$scan/$print/;
   }

   print $content;
}
```

---

Note how I didn't use `/e`. If you were using `/e` in the hopes of getting `$1` to work, that's not the right approach. Use [String::Substitution](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Substitution) instead.

For example, you can replace

```perl
# Doesn't support $1 and such. Doesn't require `\` to be escaped.
$content =~ s/$scan/$print/;
```

with

```perl
use String::Substitution qw( sub_modify );

# Supports $1 and such. Requires `\` to be escaped.
sub_modify( $content, $scan, $print );
```